# Control Expander Controls expansion amount

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, expander

I'm not even sure I asked that right.  What I am trying to ask is if there is a way to control how far the `Expander` control expands and contracts.  I am trying to get it to leave the top "row" visible when it's collapsed.  Make sense?

This is a WPF, .Net 4.5 app using Telerik's latest `RadExpander` control.

Comment: Not really sure whats you're asking. Expanders typically expand a far as the length for whats inside it.  What do you mean the top row?

Comment: Oh scratch that, didn't see the "RadExpander" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `HeaderTemplate` to define a `DataTemplate` for the header. The header is always visible.

Comment: This is close enough.  It's actually what I was trying to do when I had the epiphany that I was over complicating it and simply decided to use the controls the way they were meant to be used... :)

Comment: You can use `Header` property and define the UI directly in it. I find that using templates is more flexible in the long run, even if it means more work in the beginning.